# Entity Framework Core : cannot translate a query

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I am trying to develop a query with Entity Framework Core 8, and I'm getting an error that the LINQ expression cannot be translated.

I've created a fictional scenario to represent the problem; however, the code is the same.

In a scenario with the entities `Confederation`, `Championship` and `Team`, a confederation can have multiple championships, and a championship can have multiple teams. Championships are created in the confederation registration, meaning they don't have a unique identifier yet.

Since two confederations cannot have exactly the same championships, it is necessary to compare the IDs of the teams in the championships to validate the duplication of a confederation, as the championships do not have an ID.

This is my code:

```
_context.Confederations
    .Where(c => c.Championships
        .Where(ch => confederations.Championships
            .Where(ca => ca.Teams
                .Where(t => ch.Teams.Any(te => te.Id == t.Id))
                .Count() == ch.Teams.Count())
            .Any())
        .Count() == confederations.Championships.Count)
    .Any();
```

And I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: For complex queries that cannot be translated, consider using raw SQL queries or stored procedures.

Comment: otherwise you will need to do `_context.Confederations.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Championships.Where(.... your code here` and put it into memory, which can explode fast in memory size, you will most likely have to do the for each where clause of your linq

Comment: You can use only `Contains` with local collections. I mean `confederations.Championships` is local collection.